# Transaction cannot proceed STATUS_MARKED_ROLLBACK when running on jboss standalone

Tags: hibernate, jboss, ejb, jboss7.x, java-ee-6

Does anyone experience the following issue?

I'm able to successfully build, deploy and run my javaee6 application in jboss inside eclipse using jboss tools. But when we deployed it on another server running on standalone we got an error. I tried it the same machine where eclipse is and run on jboss as standalone and got the same error.

See error below, I've removed some parts.

```
06:53:46,423 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Transaction cannot proceed STATUS_MARKED_ROLLBACK
06:53:46,424 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1) JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component OfferTemplateServiceApi for method public void org.meveo.asg.api.OfferTemplateServiceApi.preProcessRequest(org.meveo.api.dto.OfferDto) throws org.meveo.api.exception.MeveoApiException: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction rolled back
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleEndTransactionException(CMTTxInterceptor.java:114) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.endTransaction(CMTTxInterceptor.java:94) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:252) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.requiresNew(CMTTxInterceptor.java:339) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:216) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:55) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:165) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:182) [jboss-as-ee-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final-redhat-2.jar:1.1.1.Final-redhat-2]
    ...
Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: ARJUNA016053: Could not commit transaction.
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1177)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.commit(BaseTransaction.java:126)
    at com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.commit(BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.java:75)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.endTransaction(CMTTxInterceptor.java:91) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    ... 92 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not inspect JDBC autocommit mode
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.isAutoCommit(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:311) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionCoordinatorImpl.afterNonTransactionalQuery(TransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:195) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.afterOperation(SessionImpl.java:599) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.getReference(SessionImpl.java:2458) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:983) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.wrapStaleStateException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1410) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1329) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1310) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1316) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl$CallbackExceptionMapperImpl.mapManagedFlushFailure(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1510) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorImpl.java:117) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.RegisteredSynchronization.beforeCompletion(RegisteredSynchronization.java:53) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.SynchronizationImple.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationImple.java:76)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:273)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.end(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:93)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.AtomicAction.commit(AtomicAction.java:162)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1165)
    ... 95 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Transaction cannot proceed STATUS_MARKED_ROLLBACK
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.checkTransactionActive(WrapperDataSource.java:254)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.checkTransactionActive(WrappedConnection.java:1599)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.checkStatus(WrappedConnection.java:1614)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.getAutoCommit(WrappedConnection.java:731)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.isAutoCommit(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:308) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    ... 111 more
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to solved this issue but not until I've changed the logging of `org.jboss` and `org.hibernate` to `DEBUG` mode. In my case there was an OptimisticLockException that was thrown and was wrapped that's why it was hard to figure out without the full log trace.

Comment: It's a bit late to ask this question, but I would like to know in which file to add this logging property?

Comment: The file is inside JBoss standalone/configuration folder - standalone.xml

Comment: @czetsuya can I ask for help, specifically how did you set this in standalone.xml? Pasting your standalone.xml would be a big help because I don't know how to set this. Thanks much!

Comment: Hi @RichardDomingo it should be under the sub section:
 <profile>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.1">

You could add a logger like this:
<logger category="com.czetsuyatech">
                <level name="DEBUG"/>
            </logger>